# Is there an alternative to "not not" when declaring a predicate to indicate value of strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Assuming I have `some_str_value` and I would like to have a predicate variable to indicate whether or not this value is "Truthy" (has a value).

The verbose way would be:

`predicate = some_str_value is not None and len(some_str_value) > 0`

one could also write:

`predicate = not not some_str_value`

1. Is there a shorter way than this awkwardly unzenful syntax?
2. If not, is there a common straightforward alternative?

Comment: " a predicate variable to indicate whether or not this value is "Truely" (has a value)." Do you mean "truthy"?

Comment: probably.. editing it.

Comment: Well, for starters, `len(some_str_value) > 0` can be replaced with just `some_str_value` in a boolean context, but you seem to just want `bool(some_str_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `bool`, i.e. whether or not a value is "truthy"

```
>>> bool("hi")
True
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool(None)
False
```

Note, to be pedantic, this doesn't really mean the same thing as "has a value". If a variable is defined in Python, then it has *some value*. For most built-in containers, and I suppose stings, the idea is that it is "non-empty".

I will also note that having this `predicate` variable is almost always redundant. Because basically every place you would use `predicate`, e.g.:

```
if predicate:
    do_something()
```

You could always just replace it with:

```
if some_str_value:
    do_something()
```

So, I would just caution that this might not be needed at all.

Of course, in *some* cases, you do want a `bool` object, e.g. counting the number of non-empty strings in a list:

```
>>> sum(map(bool, ["foo", "", "bar", ""]))
2
```

Comment: you overkilled the answer :)
funny bool did not come up to mind...
you are right that a predicate in this simplified context is redundant, however having it used in many conditions along-side other predicates every time is very useful for readability